# Count dataGridCells value occurence

Tags: c#

I want to know how much `0` there is in `dataGridRows.Cells[1]`. I added this code to `dataGridView1_RowPostPaint` event.

```
private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    int count=0;

    if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1)
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        count++;
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(cell) == 0)
            {
                label3.Text = count.ToString();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried with this:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
{
    int count=0;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        count++;
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
            if (cell.Value.ToString() == "0")
            {
                label3.Text = count.ToString();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

None of wchich works properly. First one just does not counting at all. Second code gives me an error related with `An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in skraper.exe but was not handled in user code`

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Do you want to know how many times the number '0' shows up in all cells?

Comment: I want to know how many cells has only "0" as a cell's content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user is allowed to add rows himself right? That last row is detectable by code, but it's values are null. There of the `NullReferenceException`. So here's the thing you do:

```
int zeros = 0;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) // For every row
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) // For every cell in the current row
        if (cell.Value != null) // If cell's value is not null
            if (cell.Value.ToString() == "0") // If cell's value is "0"
                zeros++; // Increase count

MessageBox.Show(zeros.ToString()); // Show result
```

I hope this helps.